# Does any OS support ZFS on MIPS?

Tags: linux, bsd, zfs, opensolaris, mips

Does there exist an operating system supporting [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) under the [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) architecture?

If so, *which* operating system(s)?

I am especially interested in:

- Support for ZFS on [Loongson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loongson).
- OSes [free from](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Binary_blob&oldid=580695702#Acceptance) binary blobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was an effort to port FreeBSD to mips/loongson, but it seems that this port was not marked as "stable enough" to be compiled and distributed. Additional info:

- https://wiki.freebsd.org/SOC2010VladimirSerbinenko
- http://www.freebsdnews.net/2010/04/26/google-soc-2010-freebsd-projects/
- http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-mips/2010-September/author.html
- http://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?t=7357

The best you could do is to give AWAY Zfs on this architecture, or wait for any FreeBSD move on this hardware. Why?

- OpenBSD runs smooth on Loongson, but it does not have(and will not, if zfs remain CDDL licensed) zfs support.
- FreeBSD loongson port was not reviewed and marked as "production ready"
- NetBSD has zfs just on i386/amd64 - http://wiki.netbsd.org/users/haad/porting_zfs/ . NetBSD-current have some port work being done to this architecture, but i really don´t know the real state of it - http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/sys/arch/evbmips/loongson/ - http://wiki.netbsd.org/ports/evbmips/
- IllumOS does not support loongson
- Even Debian having a port to loongson/mips compiled, zfsonlinux just works with amd64, and the package zfs-fuse have ports to amd64, i386, sparc and powerpc only.

Comment: Thanks! Let's hope ZFS makes it to MIPS/Loongson eventually!

Comment: For sure. And with OpenZFS, create a common user userbase that will allow this filesystem across many OSes without being crippled with the licensing issues that zfs have. :) - http://open-zfs.org/wiki/Main_Page